# What is the decrease in the number of tickets sold if the price rises with 5 $ .

Tags: linear-algebra

The number B of concert tickets that can be sold to K $ per
ticket is a linear function B ( k ), where  10 <=K <= 40.
applies to B ( 10) = 550, and B (40 ) = 0.

a) What is the decrease in the number of tickets sold if the price rises
with 5 $ .

Comment: sorry for that, hope its ok now

Comment: You should also try to show what you have tried to do yourself in this question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, since B is a linear function of K
Then we can assume the solution as $$ B(K) = aK+c$$
Substituting with the initial conditions leads to 
$$ 550 = 10a + c\\ 0 = 40a + c\\ a=-55/3$$ 
Therefore the decrease in B is 
$$\Delta B= B_1 - B_2 = a(K_1 - K_2)=-55/3*-5=275/3 =92\  tickets\ approx.$$

Comment: @Sara Welcome..